Alternative matrix over $\Bbb{F}_2$ and its rank
It is known that the rank of an alternating matrix is generally even. This is because it has a standard form consisting of even-dimensional matrices with 1 and 1 in the anti-diagonal entries arranged in 2×2 blocks.
My question is, what about alternating matrices over $\Bbb{F}_2$?
If we define an alternating matrix over $\Bbb{F}_2$ by the property $A^t=-A$, then for example, a 1×1 matrix with entry 1 would have odd rank. Is it common to define alternating matrices over $\Bbb{F}_2$ with an additional condition that diagonal entries must be zero, in addition to the property $A^t=-A$?

An alternative matrix corresponds to alternating forms, i.e., bilinear forms $V\times V\to k$ such that $(v,v)=0$. Note that $(v,v)=0$ implies $(v,w)=-(w,v)$ since
$$0=(v+w,v+w)=(v,v)+(w,w)+(v,w)+(w,v)=(v,w)+(w,v).$$
Moreover, the converse is true in characteristic $\ne2$ since substituting $v=w$ into $(v,w)=-(w,v)$ gives $2(v,v)=0$. However, in characteristic $2$ these two conditions are not equivalent.
Matrices $A$ gives rise to bilinear forms $V\times V\to k$ by $(v,w):=v^TAw$. Now, the condition $(v,w)=-(w,v)$ is equivalent to $A^T=-A$, so $A$ being alternating is equivalent to the associated bilinear form being alternating in characteristic $\ne2$. In characteristic two, this still holds if you say a matrix $A$ is alternating if and only if $A^T=-A$ and its diagonal entries are zero.
To conclude: a bilinear form is alternating if $(v,v)=0$ for all $v\in V$, and a matrix $A$ is alternating if the associated bilinear form is alternating. Concretely, this is exactly the condition you give.
